# XCode debugging. How can I see where my code fails ? I get no stacktrace

Tags: xcode, debugging

Currently I am struggling to find out where my code fails.
Xcode sometimes gives me a stacktrace, but currently is doesn't.
I just get an error msg in my console like: `*** -[CFString copyWithZone:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xbe10d80`. But sometimes I don't get an error message in my console at all when my app crashes. How can I figure out where the problem acually occurs? How do you guys locate your problems?

Perhaps someone knows a few environment settings that can help?

Comment: Do you actually run with the debugger attached, or just in debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Instruments (/Developer/Applications/Instruments) to help detect usage of zombie objects. Here is a [link](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/) to a tutorial to use it to detect memory leaks, but there it can also be used for other purposes.

Comment: Yep, I know. But why doesn't XCode give me a stacktrace?

Comment: It does not answer my problem of not getting stacktraces on crashes, but it helps stepping through and in the end figuring out whats wrong... Hopefully XCode4 does a better job....

Comment: This doesn't answer the problem of how to get a stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Debugger then click Breakpoint. then run ur app u can see where error occuring